# MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL using Sequel Pro but I keep getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Please help

Below is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE custname()
BEGIN
SELECT fname
FROM 062016_CustomerFile 
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: please indent your code better, no one will find what is your line 5

Comment: DELIMITER //                                                                                          CREATE PROCEDURE custname()                                                                  BEGIN                                                                                                     SELECT fname                                                                                            FROM 062016_CustomerFile                                                                          END // DELIMITER ;

Comment: i don't seem to be able to write the code properly here. line 5 starts from "FROM 062016_Customerfile"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon after the table name.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE custname()
BEGIN
SELECT fname
FROM 062016_CustomerFile;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Note: your table name can be quoted (enclosed with backticks) but it is not required here.
From the documentation: [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.